# Windows 10 file association selection

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I'm using **Windows 10** *version 1803* and cannot change file association via

```
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs
```

After choosing the "**default application by type**" option, there's no way to browse the file system to search for a specific software/app. The only two options are **the file's currently associated software/app** and "**look for an app in the store**" as shown in the below screen shot.

---

**Question**

How can I associate the file to another and very specific software/app that I can browse to choose?

[image: FIGURE]

Comment: While I am uncertain of this bug or whatever it may be. Here is another way you can set it: https://superuser.com/a/841498/543035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this to workaround that limitation you wrote about where it doesn't let you select other apps to associate, etc. but I'll write a simple solution you can use.

> 1. Create a dummy file with the extension you wish to associate with a specific program if you don't have an actual file already (e.g.
>      `test.region`) *right-click* on it and select **Open With**
>
>    [image]
> 2. When the **How do you want to open this file?** window pops up, ensure that the option **Always use this app to open <`.ext`> files** *is checked*
>      and then select **More apps**
>
>    [image]
> 3. You will then have a scroll bar that you can navigate to select the app you want the file to open with if it's listed. Otherwise,
>      at the bottom of the scrollable list you can select the option **Look for
>      another app on this PC**. Then when the **Open with** window opens you can navigate
>      the file system and find the app you want the file to open with and
>      double click it and you'll be all set.
>
>    [image]
>      [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [How to Fix the Missing “Open with” Option on the Windows 10 Right-Click Context Menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/261076/how-to-fix-the-missing-open-with-option-on-the-windows-10-right-click-context-menu/)
- [How do I set a default app for an extension that is not listed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1296013/how-do-i-set-a-default-app-for-an-extension-that-is-not-listed/1296105#1296105)

Comment: @Gab - See my post on https://superuser.com/questions/1296013/how-do-i-set-a-default-app-for-an-extension-that-is-not-listed/1296105#1296105 where you could simply use `ASSOC .region=<regionfile>` assuming the `ftype` is already setup and you know this information otherwise you can probably just use the simple workaround with the GUI options rather than command line and get it to work just fine.